# what is the purpose of using the XOR operator and this line "if (current & 1)" "current = exclusive >> I;"

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
#include "main.h"
/**
 * flip_bits - count the number of bits to change
 * to get from one number to another
 * @n: the first number
 * @m: second number
 * Return: the number of bits needed to change
 */

unsigned int flip_bits(unsigned long int n, unsigned long int m)
{

  int i, count = 0;
  unsigned long int current;
  unsigned long int exclusive = n ^ m;
  for (i = 63; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    current = exclusive >> i;
    if (current & 1)
      count++;
  }

  return (count);
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the XOR operator does? Do you know what the `&` operator does? The question changes depending on your context.

Comment: Do you understand the block comment in the function? I mean, would you feel comfortable using this function even if you only had the comment and its signature? (if the body was private and you didn't have access to it)

Comment: have you tried doing what the function does on paper with much smaller values (like 4 bit)?

Comment: @Rinkesh no I'm a beginner trying to find a way around this bit manipulation thing

Comment: @Dr.NatnaelM which is exactly why you should do it on paper first.

Comment: It counts the number of bits that are different in `n` and `m`. First the XOR produces a new value: each bit of it will be a `0` if that bit position had *the same* value in `n` and `m`, and a `1` if *different* values in `n` amd `m`. The `& 1` examines the state of bit 0 (after aligning each bit to that location).

Comment: See also [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of XOR operation is that it returns a `1` **when two operands(bits) are different** and `0` **if they are same**. So XOR of two numbers would give you a value which when interpreted in binary shows the **bit position where the two numbers differ**. And to get the count of number of bits to change all you need to do is count the number of `1`s in the result of XOR.

```
current = exclusive >> i;
```

this line shifts MSB of exclusive, bringing it to LSB and assigns it to `current`. And the line below

```
if (current & 1) 
   count++;
```

is doing a check whether the LSB of current(i.e. MSB of XOR result) is `1` or not(since 1 in binary is all zeros except LSB 1 and) counting that.

These lines are in a loop so in all it is checking for each position if it is a `1` and counting it. You can do it the other way around as well going from LSB to MSB but that is a messier way, and you should perhaps use `sizeof(unsigned long int)*8 - 1` as the initial value of `i` in your for loop instead of `63`, as the sizes are platform dependent.